# Matlab Sum of series for the following-> expression

Tags: matlab, sum, series

I don't get how to use sum of series for:

[image]

I have to compute `t` number of the sum of series, so just don't care about the character `t` there. My elements are from a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following commands (assuming the input vector is `x`):

```
x = rand(1,100);
y = sum(diff(x).^2);
```

The `diff` calculates the differences-vector of the neighboring entries of `x`, which is then squared and summed.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm a beginner in using this website:D. Thanks!